# Copying Excel sheet to all Workbooks in directory

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not too versed in VBA so hopefully someone can help me. I've searched around for a VBA macro I could edit for my needs but none of them worked.

I'm trying to copy my Worksheet into all of my Workbooks in the directory. For example I want the worksheet from the workbook "Template" with the sheet/current sheet of "Daily" into all of my workbooks in the folder or which ever folder I choose in the code. This way I can easily copy the sheet into the workbook without having to do it hundreds of time manually.

However I have no clue where to start and the one I've looked into doesn't seem to work very well for me.

Comment: You may not like this suggestion, but i would recommend using this opportunity to learn a server side language like python.  Doing this in python would be very easy.  You should get away from doing these types of things with VBA.  If your up for the challenge, and want help with a python script, let me know.  If not, im sure someone will present an alternative VBA solution shortly  :)

Comment: This kind of project is a great one to begin with learning to code in VBA.  I would suggest starting with one of the many Excel VBA tutorials on the web (just Google "Excel VBA"), and use Microsoft's VBA help (which is very good for the most part) and this site for specifics if/when you get stuck.  Good luck!

Comment: @Eric - Can you explain a little more how you could use Python for this (and why)?  I'm learning Python too (and VBA), and am curious. Would the Python code just be way easy to do, compared to VBA? Or quicker,?  and OP, with the keywords "VBA open files in directory", "VBA copy worksheet to external workbook", and "VBA avoid using `.Select`" should get you going pretty quickly.

Comment: Hey Batman, sure, no problem.  I would go with python because it's a high level language (meaning its syntactically short and therefore easy to learn, debug, and code), it's extremely versatile and capable of being used for many purposes (such as general programming, web application development, and machine learning), lastly, there is a TON of documentation and existing code out there that you can leverage to make your own quick scripts.  So, if you have the choice of learning how to do it in a limited language like VBA or python I'd learn it in python.

Comment: I'd be happy to show you a script i have to accomplish something similar but i don't want to post it on this thread. Please open a new question and send me the link and i'll answer it there.

Comment: Write down "pseudo code", i.e. what you want to accomplish in English sentences, line by line. For example: "1. Define template sheet, 2. Define target folder, 3. Loop through all Excel files in that folder....". Then research line by line how to do it and play around with the "macro recorder" to get to the needed VBA commands.

Answer (score 1):

Open your Template workbook, assign the correct folder location to loopFolder, and then try this:

```
Sub copyWorksheet()

    'this sets your template workbook/worksheet
    Dim copyWB As Workbook
    Dim copyWS As Worksheet

    Set copyWB = Workbooks("Template")
    Set copyWS = copyWB.Sheets("Daily")

    'this creates a collection of all filenames to be processed
    Dim loopFolder As String
    Dim fileNm As Variant
    Dim myFiles As New Collection

    '''don't forget the backslash before the final double-quote below
    loopFolder = "C:\Documents\desiredFolder\"
    fileNm = Dir(loopFolder & "*.xlsx")

    Do While fileNm <> ""
        myFiles.Add fileNm
        fileNm = Dir
    Loop

    'this loops through all filenames and copies your copyWS to the beginning
    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each fileNm In myFiles
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=(loopFolder & fileNm))
        copyWS.Copy after:=wb.Sheets(1)
        wb.Save
        wb.Close
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set copyWB = Workbooks("Template")`

Should be

`Set copyWB = Workbooks("Template.xlsx")`